# How to detect mobile browser using jQuery or in some other SIMPLE way..?

Tags: jquery, mobile, detect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to detect handheld device in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)

I want to make a mobile version of my web app. How I can run a function that will detect if a request is being made from a desktop or mobile browser?

This is so that if the user is requesting from a mobile browser and they click on a link, rather than go to the actual page, it should get hijacked and do some other event..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 8):

There are a few scripts on [Detect Mobile Browser](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/) that redirect mobile visitors on the server side or with JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the following to get the platform

```
navigator.platform
```

And this to get the browser app

```
navigator.appName
```

Example:

```
// Detects if it is an Android device
var android = (navigator.platform.indexOf("android")>=0);
if (android) {
   // Do something
}
```

Also, there is the [Advanced Browser Check jQuery Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/advbrowsercheck), though it seems like it might be overkill.

Comment: exactly what I need. is the transition works well in apple devices?

Comment: and is navigator.platform can return the platform version? do you have where jquerymobile crashes in devices?